# Kibana 6.5.4 unable to delete an index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I am a beginner of Kibana 6.5.4  and I added an index pattern. Then I wanted to delete it but I could not do it... there are sth wrong as described in the picture. My computer is Macbook 12 with system 10.12.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your index is locked; most likely because you hit the [flood stage watermark](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html), meaning your disk had less than 5% space left.

First, add more free disk space or change the flood stage watermark. For example set it to 100MB (but I would only recommend that for a dev system — might be a little too close for production):

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "100mb",
    "cluster.info.update.interval": "10s"
  }
}
```

Unlock your index; either the specific one (here `my-index`) or you could also use `_all`:

```
PUT my-index/_settings
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
}
```

Comment: I have now about 100 gb free disk space, and I tried: 
`PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "50gb",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "25gb",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "2gb",
    "cluster.info.update.interval": "1m"
  }
}` and it returned true, BUT I can not still delete or create anything. It always reads: Forbidden.

Comment: Oh wait, I might have misread the error and it‘s something else. Can you add the log of Elasticsearch to your original question?